# Run some script on mysql start

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, bash, triggers

I want added some like trigger to mysql when mysql start. So I have MEMORY table and cron script which dump this table each 1 hour. I want fill this table form dump when mysql start.

How can I do that?  I understand that I can create bash script which will be run mysql and import dump, but I want to do this via mysql facilities.  Maybe exists some trigger or event which execute when mysql run.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the [`init-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) option (either on the command line, or in your option file).