# Execute a trigger after MYSQL restart

Tags: mysql, triggers, primary-key

I would like to initialize the primary key  (based on certain validations) of a table at restart of mysql. Is there any event at mysql restart. The idea is to execute a TRIGGER after a mysql restart. The trigger would calculate my Primary Key ID.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829588/run-some-script-on-mysql-start